# Unable to get sort Array to work

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php sort($array) not working - returning 1 instead of sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443493/php-sortarray-not-working-returning-1-instead-of-sorted-array)

I'm having a difficult time getting array sort() function to work as expected, I've also tried ksort() etc. :::

**This Works Fine**

```
foreach( (array) $query as $post ) {
   $VP = ( ( empty($PMD['vehicle_price'][0]) ) ?  $VP = 'On Request' : $VP = $PMD['vehicle_price'][0] ); 
      $vehicle_p[] = $VP;
}

$return = array_count_values($vehicle_p); //Key Value Unique ( count )

foreach($return as $value => $count) {
   <li><span class="key">' . $value . '</span> (' . $count . ')</li>
}
```

**End Result:** 480000 (1), 80000 (2), 120400 (1)

I now want to sort this so 80000 (2) is first in list folowed by 120400 (1) then 480000 (1)

As soon as I add any **sort()** function like below I only get an output 1

I'm not able to get this to work any help would bew appreciated

```
$return = array_count_values($vehicle_p); //Key Value Unique ( count )
$return = sort($return);
print_r($return);
```

Comment: To quickly explain to people who find this (as it returns #1 on Google):
It's because you have `$return = sort( $return )`. 
sort returns true or false on completion. Therefore in this code, you are overwriting $return where you are likely expecting $return to become a sorted array. 

Replace  `$return = sort($return)` with: `sort($return)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to sort the array by ascending values? if this is correct Look at `asort()` which will sort the array by value but keep the index/key intact

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Keep in mind that the sort functions return a Boolean so don't assign them to a variable, just call the function on the array.

```
asort($array);
```

Comment: asort give me same result as my comment above

Comment: are you doing `$return = asort($return);` or just `asort($return);`

Comment: THX for your feedback worked 100%

Answer (score 5):

the [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function returns a boolean value.

So, you are effectively overwriting the contents of `$return` after it has been sorted by assigning this boolean to `$return`.

Simply do

```
sort($return);
```

Comment: $return = array_count_values($vehicle_p); //Key Value Unique ( count )
 $return = sort($return);
 print_r($return);

 This prints "1" and my foreach == Warning: Invalid Argument Supplied For Foreach()

Comment: `$return = sort($return);` the sort() function returns a boolean value (1 is a boolean value). Don't assign the result of sort to `$return`. Simply do `sort($return);`